# Add a marker to my map

Tags: ios, dictionary, mapkit, marker

I'm new to iOS, and it's so different from Android logic that I can't find how to add a marker to a map :-|

I've added a `MKMapView` to my `xib`

I've added this code to my .m (trimmed)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface Dove ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mappa;

@end
#define METERS_PER_MILE 1609.344
@implementation Dove
- (IBAction)vaiHome:(id)sender {
    Index *second = [[Index alloc] initWithNibName:@"Index" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:second animated:YES completion:nil];
}
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 45.40170;
    zoomLocation.longitude= 8.91552;
    MKCoordinateRegion viewRegion = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(zoomLocation, METERS_PER_MILE, METERS_PER_MILE);
    [_mappa setRegion:viewRegion animated:YES];
    [_mappa regionThatFits:viewRegion];
}
```

Now, how can I display a pin at that position? It should simple, but I can't find a solution :-|
Also, the map remain in united states but it most go to the marker.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Please read the [Annotating Maps](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW1) section of Apple's Location and Maps Programming Guide (the rest of the Guide is recommended as well).  The simple answer is: Create an MKPointAnnotation object, set its properties, and call addAnnotation.  There must be hundreds of answers for this just on SO.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to setup the annotation marker (call this in your viewdidload):

```
- (void)setupAnnotation
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D zoomLocation;
    zoomLocation.latitude = 45.40170;
    zoomLocation.longitude= 8.91552;

    NARMapViewAnnotation* annot = [[NARMapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithCoord:zoomLocation];
    [_mapView addAnnotation:annot];
}
```

Then you have to setup the MKMapViewDelegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mv didAddAnnotationViews:(NSArray *)views
{
    MKAnnotationView* annotView = [views objectAtIndex:0];
    id<MKAnnotation> mp = [annotView annotation];
    MKCoordinateRegion region = [mv regionThatFits:MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance([mp coordinate], REGION_WINDOW, REGION_WINDOW)];
    [mv setRegion:region animated:YES];
}
```

NARMapViewAnnotation:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface NARMapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation>

@property (nonatomic, assign) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord;

@end

#import "NARMapViewAnnotation.h"

@implementation NARMapViewAnnotation

- (id)initWithCoord:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)coord
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _coordinate = coord;
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

Comment: sorry but i don't get it, because i receive an error for undeclared identifier NARMapViewAnnotation and annot

Comment: ah sorry. That is a custom annotation marker you create. I'll add code for it

Comment: it told me there's no visible @interface initWithCoord in NARMapViewAnnotation

Comment: Make sure you spelled it right then? It's right there in the NARMapViewAnnotation class.